System session has transitioned from 1 to 3. Reason InputAccelerometer. But I don't have an accelerometer
So I checked my Event Viewer > System, and found this 566 message from Kernel-Power:

The system session has transitioned from 1 to 3. Reason
InputAccelerometer

So am I understanding this correctly: it's going into sleep mode (1->3 (which is S2)), BECAUSE an input device's ACCELEROMETER is making it SLEEP?

This device does not have any accelerometers, and I only have a cheap printer and a cheap monitor and a cheap office mouse plugged in.
How can a motion sensor, trigger sleep, via motion? I understand if a wake is triggered by an accelerometer, but how does -acceleration-, sleep the pc?

Perhaps there is some misbehaving driver/app (like from some VR headset -- which is 1000% not even in the house right now)?

Is Visual Studio installed on the computer? I think that can have some emulators installed for some systems which have accelerometers.

Actually, I'm surprised that when I came in later (with sleep disabled) and unlocked this pc, it gave me "The system session has transitioned from 7 to 9. Reason InputAccelerometer " --- this was definitely me -- either the mouse or keyboard. Still doesn't explain why "input / accelerometer" would CAUSE sleep though. (or I completely misunderstand the wording of these messages..

I'm experiencing this same issue: Windows 11 going to sleep, and blaming "InputAccelerometer" (no idea why). I was also in the middle of a game when it went to sleep, so I suspected overheating, but I don't see anything in the event log that mentions temperature. I'm on a cheap mini-pc: TRIGKEY S7
